# When to use OpenGL Display Lists?

Tags: c, opengl

I am currently working on a project where I am attempting to recreate [this logo](http://www.newbelgium.com/Images/Shiftcircle.jpg) but animate the gears on top of the static things. Now this is what I have created so far...

[image]

So far it is looking nice and I am moving onto the gears today. While doing some research on the gears I came across display lists in openGL and have read a little about them. It seems that they are good for performance as they reduce the need to redraw content over and over like when I move my camera around the sign and/or when the gears are moving. What I have so far is just a ton of polygons that make up the sign background and the letters. The curved letters are made up of a ton of triangle polygons.

So my main question is, before I move onto getting the gears created, should I take the time to create display lists for the content I already have? Or is it just not necessary? I am basing my gears off the famous gears.c which uses display lists, so I most likely will use them there.

Comment: **never** they are deprecated in favor of VBOs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you're rendering your objects at the moment.

If you're using immediate mode (`glBegin`/`glVertex`/`glEnd`), then wrapping the display lists will help. But both immediate mode rendering and display lists are depreciated starting with OpenGL 3, and switching to vertex buffer objects (VBOs) will likely net a better performance increase (at the expense of rewriting a bit of code).

If you're already using VBOs, then wrapping those calls in a display list will likely not make any difference.

https://open.gl/ is a nice tutorial for modern OpenGL.

Comment: The class that I am in is being taught with older OpenGL stuff because I guess it is easier to grasp. In any case, we are using immediate mode for a lot of things, so that is what I have done to create the above.

Comment: @SeanCallahan: I found immediate mode to complicate things and make the inner workings of OpenGL harder to understand for students. IMHO every teacher who still covers immediate mode in his classes should get his attitude adjusted in a radical way.